# Discrete GPU throttles after rMBP (late 2016) has been on for a while

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, gpu, high-sierra

I'm running the High Sierra (developer) beta build 17A315i on my late 2016 Macbook Pro with Radeon 455 GPU.

After a while, the discrete GPU's performance decreases significantly. The openCL score on Geekbench goes to 13k from 40k and FPS dips in all games. It seems that it is not using it's full potential since the fans do not really ramp up. Only a restart fixes the problem temporarily for a few hours before it goes back down even if I close all other applications. The intel GPU is unaffected.

Can anyone identify what I can try? No one has reported that it's the bug in the beta. What can I do to solve this issue? I've reset the NVRAM and SMC already, which didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Our work lab Mac typically run very well for a week to a month between reboots. On high Sierra, since the initial build - we are seeing stability degrade from hours to days instead of weeks.

If you can report your details - tests, scripts, sample files or apps - to Apple, you'll likely get some sort of explanation or learn when it’s fixed. In fairness, this isn’t unusual for beta and for new system chipsets and both of these are in play. Also, most of our apps are absolutely not ready yet and the filesystem is also still being tuned, tweaked and functions rolled out.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll try and report my findings to Apple.